# How do I fix unwanted sharp edges baked onto a normal map?

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-baking

[image]

In modeling this knife and handle, I am attempting to bake the high poly mesh onto a low poly version so this can used in game engines, etc. But as I try to bake it, the normal maps aren't looking like I want them to be, I see some smoothing with the jagged edges of the low poly mesh, and the render result is horrendous. I suspect that it could be a uv-unwrapping problem, or that the two meshes versions are more suited for a displacement map, but I am a bit new to this workflow.

[Here is a link to the .blend file, knife.blend](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/MxIUv7n724)

Comment: I suspect this is an issue arising from the differences between the high and low mesh, but the files you provide are only the high-poly meshes.  What are you trying to bake onto?

Comment: The low-poly meshes are on layer 2 of knife.blend